# Python - get dictionary value from a splitted string

Tags: python

Take a look at the code below. Basically I have a dictionary which might look like the data point below. I then wanna send a string into a function to fetch the corresponding dictionary value.

The code below works, however - it's not good code obviously. How would I go about rewriting this so that I could handle deeper dictionary that might be nested 10 or 20 times?

```
data = """{
  "data": {
    "person": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "surname": "Smith",
    }
    "cars": [
    {
        "car": {
        "model": "Toyota"
        }
    }
    ]
  }
}
"""

def get_data(key):
    if '.' in key:
        splitted = key.split(".")
        x = 0
        # Change to integer
        for entry in splitted:
            if entry.isdigit():
                splitted[x] = int(entry)
            x += 1
        if len(splitted) == 0:
            raise Exception("Need atleast one data point")
        elif len(splitted) == 1:
            filtered_data = data['data'][splitted[0]]
        elif len(splitted) == 2:
            filtered_data = data['data'][splitted[0]][splitted[1]]
        elif len(splitted) == 3:
            filtered_data = data['data'][splitted[0]][splitted[1]][splitted[2]]
        elif len(splitted) == 4:
            filtered_data = data['data'][splitted[0]][splitted[1]][splitted[2]][splitted[3]]                        
        return filtered_data        
    
get_data("person.firstname") == 'John'
get_data("person.surname") == 'Smith'
get_data("person.cars.0.model") == 'Toyota'
```

Comment: Seems like you can try with a recursive function.

Comment: There's a misplaced `,`: `... "Smith",}` should be `... "Smith"},`. Why don't you read the dict with `json.loads` (`import json`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` library as following:

```
import json
  
test_string = '{"data":{"person":{"firstname": "John", "surname": "Smith"},"cars":[{"car":{"model": "Toyota"}}]}}' 
res = json.loads(test_string)


print(res['data']['person']['firstname'])
print(res['data']['person']['surname'])
print(res['data']['cars'][0]['car']['model'])
```

which outputs:

```
>> John
>> Smith
>> Toyota
```

Make sure you have the correct format, because what you have in the example, it's not a correct format that would work.

```
{
  "data": {
    "person": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "surname": "Smith", -> THIS COMA SHOULD BE HERE
    } -> HERE NEEDS A COMA
    "cars": [
    {
        "car": {
        "model": "Toyota"
        }
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following version of your code which is the modified version, it supports nesting to any level, just make sure your query string is valid as in your example you are not passing correct order e.g. the car is not part of persons object but it's the sibling of the persons

```
import json

data = '{"data":{"person":{"firstname": "John", "surname": "Smith"},"cars":[{"car":{"model": "Toyota"}}]}}'

def GetData(data, q):
    try:
        jdata = json.loads(data)
        params = q.split('.')
        last = False
        for param in params:
            param = int(param) if param.isdigit() else param
            last = jdata[param] if last is False else last[param]
        return last
    except:
        return None

print(GetData(data, 'data.person.firstname')) #John
print(GetData(data, 'data.person.lastname')) #Smith
print(GetData(data, 'data.cars.0.car.model')) #Toyota
print(GetData(data, 'data.cars.0.car.model.test')) #None, Query string not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use JSON, like @alexandru-dudu said, but this means that your lookup keys won't be the same as what you provided in your question. If you really want to stick with your example, here's two possible solutions.

Few notes first:

1. I corrected the JSON format of your example like @alexandru-dudu said in is answer,
2. I corrected the last lookup key you provided to a working example.

#### Homemade script

The idea here is to use a recursive function that would process the lookup keys one by one and walk through the data deeper and deeper at each run.

```py
data = {
  "data": {
    "person": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "surname": "Smith"
    },
    "cars": [{
        "car": {
            "model": "Toyota"
        }
    }]
  }
}

def get_data(data, key: str):
    keys = key.split(".", 1)
    key = keys[0]
    if key.isdigit():
        key = int(key)
    try:
        data = data[key]
    except KeyError:
        return
    if len(keys) == 1:
        # We reach the last part of the lookup key
        return data
    # Process the data one step deeper
    return get_data(data, keys[1])

firstname = get_data(data["data"], "person.firstname")
print(firstname, firstname == "John")

lastname = get_data(data["data"], "person.surname")
print(lastname, lastname == "Smith")

car_model = get_data(data["data"], "cars.0.car.model")
print(car_model, car_model == "Toyota")
```

#### Using the more powerful tool `jq`

Turns out the ability to process and walk through JSON using lookup key format like what you shown in your example is something that is already possible using the amazing tool that is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

This tool allows you to process JSON data using key lookup and powerful filtering. It designed yo work on the command line, but there are some Python bindings available that allows you to use it right in your scripts.

Assuming you have it installed and available in your shell, here's how you would use it:

```sh
$ cat <<EOF > data
> {
>   "data": {
>     "person": {
>       "firstname": "John",
>       "surname": "Smith"
>     },
>     "cars": [{
>         "car": {
>             "model": "Toyota"
>         }
>     }]
>   }
> }
> EOF
$ cat data | jq '.data.person.firstname'
"John"
$ cat data | jq '.data.person.surname'
"Smith"
$ cat data | jq '.data.cars | .[0].car.model'
"Toyota"
```

Note that the lookup keys are a bit different than what you provided: they are all prefixed with `.data`.

Now if you wanted to use it in your Python script, you'd simply have to install the [`jq`](https://github.com/mwilliamson/jq.py)  project with pip:

```
pip install jq
```

And then you can use it like this:

```py
import jq

data = {
  "data": {
    "person": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "surname": "Smith"
    },
    "cars": [{
        "car": {
            "model": "Toyota"
        }
    }]
  }
}

def get_data(data, key):
    return jq.compile(key).input(data).first()

firstname = get_data(data["data"], ".person.firstname")
print(firstname, firstname == "John")

lastname = get_data(data["data"], ".person.surname")
print(lastname, lastname == "Smith")

car_model = get_data(data["data"], ".cars | .[0].model")
print(car_model, car_model == "Toyota")
```

Note that in this example the lookup keys are not prefixed with `.data`. That's because jq is being fed with the value of `data["data"]` in this example.

If you would like to know more about jq I suggest you go through the [tutorial](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/) and if you want to learn its syntax, I'd recommend the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), it's quite thorough and well written with examples.